# Qt 4.8.3 GUI application on Linux looks old and doesn't match the designer preview

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, qt4.8

I installed Qt 4.8.3 and Qt Creator 2.5.2 on Fedora 17 and Ubuntu 12.04.
When I create a GUI application, the visual elements look good in the Qt Designer preview window. However when I run the application, the resulting application has an older style which is inconsistent with the OS and does not match the preview in Qt Designer.

In both of the images below, the top part is the preview from Qt Designer and the bottom part is the compiled application.

- Qt was installed by compiling the source located at http://qt-project.org/downloads
- During ./configure phase of the installation, the "open source" version was chosen.
- This issue occurs whether the application is run from the OS or launched from the IDE

Is there a way to make the compiled GUI application appear properly?

**Fedora:**

- Top Half = Qt Designer preview (desired)
- Bottom Half = resulting application

[image]

**Ubuntu:**

- Top Half = Qt Designer preview (desired)
- Bottom Half = resulting application

[image]

**Addendum:**
Here is an image showing a 4.8.1 compiled application (how it's supposed to look like)
[image]

Additionally, If I install both 4.8.1 and 4.8.3 on the same computer, even 4.8.1 compiled applications will not appear properly:
[image]

Comment: have you set the qt style in your app? or check system qt style settings

Comment: In previous versions of Qt, I never needed to set the style if I wanted the GUI to match the style of the native OS. Has this changed in this version?

Comment: @DanielK No it hasn't.  I've found odd style issues can occur if `qt settings` app (might have a different name under your distro, usually has a pair of compasses as a logo) has been messed with.  I also found menus and text look odd if I don't have `glabels` installed on my system under Gnome.

Comment: @cmannett85 I found the application you were reffering to: `qtconfig` located in `Qt-4.8.3/bin`. I ran the application but the selected style is: "Desktop Settings (Default)". On 4.8.1 it is the same thing but on 4.8.1 it displays properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is solved.

When installing the Qt source, the instructions forgot to mention that a list of developer libraries must be installed prior to the ./configure step. This list can be found here: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Qt_For_Linux

Additionally, I had trouble compiling QtWebkit because of the error:

> g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fuse-ld=gold’

To solve this new problem, one of the two following solutions are possible:

- At the configure step, run configure with the `-no-webkit` option: `./configure -no-webkit`

OR

- Remove the line `QMAKE_LFLAGS+=-fuse-ls-gold` from the file `qt-everywhere.../src/3rdparty/webkit/Source/common.pri`